# how to use boardView and nested Viewpager altogether?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

**Edit--**
**i guess this structure of what i thought was wierd a bit so i decided not to code like that and just follow the rules that the library is saying.( use 1 fragment and that it ) --**

I'm using Board Library (Reference : https://github.com/woxblom/DragListView )

**board_layout.xml(Root Fragment)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <com.woxthebox.draglistview.BoardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/board_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:paddingBottom="30dp"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/card_padding"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/card_padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/card_padding"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/card_padding" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
   </com.woxthebox.draglistview.BoardView>
```

**fragment_adapter.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:id="@+id/card_view"
 app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center">
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="Story Id :"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_story_id"
        android:text="-1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="Count :"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_story_count"
        android:text="-1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </LinearLayout>
 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**recycler_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.chauthai.swipereveallayout.SwipeRevealLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/swipe_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dp"
app:dragEdge="right"
app:mode="same_level">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/delete_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="#ffcc0000">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="Delete"/>
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/front_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffb9b9">

   <include layout="@layout/vertical_recycler_item" />
  </FrameLayout>
  </com.chauthai.swipereveallayout.SwipeRevealLayout>
```

**vertical_recycler_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/card"
android:padding="10dp">

 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/txt_blood_type"
   android:text="bloodType"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_gender"
    android:text="gender"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_hobby"
    android:text="hobby"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_notification_overlay"
        android:id="@+id/arrow_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/txt_move_story"
         android:visibility="gone"
         android:text="move!"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and i'm gonna make viewPager which exteneded FragmentStatePagerAdapter with multiple fragments.

but got an **error**

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: 
HorizontalScrollView can host only one direct child

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: HorizontalScrollView can host 
only one direct child
```

i don't know what is the problem here. 
please help me thank you.

Comment: post full xml code

Comment: I am assuming that you have more than one direct child hosted in your `HorizontalScrollView` as the error is suggesting. In that case reduce the number of hosted childs to one. But without you posting at least the full XML this is not answerable.

Comment: i just added my xml code!

Comment: @jeheechoi check my answer

Answer (score 1):

> HorizontalScrollView can host only one direct child - Meaning, you have to add the components to the linearlayout/relativelayout.

```
HorizontalScrollView -> linearlayout/relativelayout -> then components
```

i.e **BoardView -> linearlayout/relativelayout -> viewpager**

Comment: Clean and rebuild then run

Answer (score 0):

> `Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: 
>       HorizontalScrollView can host only one direct child`

From [**source code**](https://github.com/woxblom/DragListView/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/woxthebox/draglistview/BoardView.java)

> **`BoardView extends HorizontalScrollView`** so you can not add multiple child in it
>
> `HorizontalScrollView` can host only one direct child
>   so you need to use single layout as as child of  your `BoardView` may be `linearlayout or relativelayout`

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <com.woxthebox.draglistview.BoardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/board_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
          android:orientation="vertical">

             //add your control here

       </LinearLayout>

</com.woxthebox.draglistview.BoardView>
```

Comment: did you dynamically view inside your **`board_view`**

Comment: oh but when i clicked a fragment, it is created another fragment dynamically with some dummy Data.

Comment: @jeheechoi this the reasong for error you need to add that fragment inside other layout not direct in to `BoardView`

Comment: but it will be created inside viewpager like using integrating viewPager with fragments.. is it still also problem?

Comment: @jeheechoi may be

Comment: still got same error when i removed viewPager and just left linear Layout .. so awkard anyway thanks for trying!

Comment: @jeheechoi remove linear layout also just boardview and run.

Comment: i know it is working when i only use boardview but i wanted to use fragments with viewPager inside boardview.. :(

Comment: @jeheechoi then add that viewpager in the item file of boardview

Comment: ok i guess thats good idea. i will try and let you know thank you !